# ASP.NET repeater over list of hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am making a pagination feature, because the default one in webforms uses postbacks, which is pathetic really.

Just wondering if there is a better way to output this List of links.

```
paginator = new Paginator(10,35);
// List<HyperLink>
rptPagination.DataSource = paginator.getPageLinks();


<asp:Repeater ID="rptPagination" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <a href="<%# Eval("NavigateUrl") %>"><%# Eval("Text") %></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Obviously if I try to change other properties of the HyperLinks, like target, visible etc this will not be rendered into the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep using that syntax and continue with pure HTML:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <a href="<%# Eval("NavigateUrl") %>" target="_blank"><%# Eval("Text") %></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Or, a server side version:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
                 NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("NavigateUrl") %>' 
                 Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: One problem I'm having is that I want to disable the link for the current page. So I can set `link.Enabled = false;`. But then how can I output this in the template. I don't understand why I can't just simply print the link out. Some frameworks like Django would let me just `{{ link }}` and be done with it.

Comment: Got it `Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' `

Comment: Keep in mind that the server-side version doesn't do exactly the same thing as the href, in that characters like "&" are replaced with "&amp;"